# Последовательное выполнение 2х функций (выполнение 2-ой ТОЛЬКО после завершения 1-ой)

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, pyqt, qtimer

Вопрос в следующем: как запустить функцию, после завершения предыдущей.
Функция в функции, но с обязательным условием отработки первой функции.

Задача, сделать фото и показать его в GUI. 
Пробовал использовать `Thread` (так же пробовал `Thread + signal` - единственный вариант, запуск через `Thread` первой задачи, которая через .`emit` после завершения посылает сигнал на запуск второй задачи, он работает, но при продолжительной работе вызывает баги и зависания приложения).

Пробовал отдельно использовать сигналы, смотрел уже в сторону `async`/`await`, не могу найти простого, но действенного решения. 
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys
import threading
import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QCamera, QCameraViewfinderSettings, QCameraImageCapture, QCameraInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QCameraViewfinder
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QScrollArea, \
    QPushButton, QSizePolicy
from win32comext.shell import shell, shellcon


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        self.available_cameras = QCameraInfo.availableCameras()
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.viewfinder.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setObjectName('main_gridlayout')
        grid.addWidget(self.update_photo_btn(), 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.viewfinder, 1, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.showImg(), 2, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.select_camera()

    def update_photo_btn(self):
        but = QPushButton('Сделать фото и Обновить')
        but.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        but.clicked.connect(self.thread)
        return but

    
    def thread(self):
        task_1 = threading.Thread(target=self.func_click_photo)
        task_1.start()
        task_1.join()
        task_2 = threading.Thread(target=self.func_updater())
        task_2.start()
        task_2.join()


    def func_click_photo(self):
        millitime = round(time.time() * 1000)
        timestamp = time.strftime(f"%d%m%Y-{millitime}")
        self.capture.capture(os.path.join(f"test-{timestamp}.jpg"))

    def func_updater(self):
        grid = self.findChild(QGridLayout, 'main_gridlayout')
        box = self.findChild(QGroupBox, 'main_groupbox')
        if grid is None:
            print('Некуда вставить новый QGroupBox!')
        elif box is None:
            grid.addWidget(self.showImg(), 2, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        else:
            grid.removeWidget(box)
            box.deleteLater()
            grid.addWidget(self.showImg(), 2, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

    def select_camera(self):
        self.camera = QCamera(self.available_cameras[0])
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)
        self.camera.setCaptureMode(QCamera.CaptureStillImage)
        self.camera.start()

        supported_formats = QCamera.supportedViewfinderResolutions(self.camera)
        height_cam = int(supported_formats[0].width())
        width_cam = int(supported_formats[0].height())

        self.setting = QCameraViewfinderSettings()
        self.setting.setResolution(height_cam, width_cam)

        self.camera.setViewfinderSettings(self.setting)
        self.capture = QCameraImageCapture(self.camera)

    def find(self, pattern, path):
        result = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for name in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                    result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
        return result

    def showImg(self):
        path = shell.SHGetKnownFolderPath(shellcon.FOLDERID_Pictures)
        all_image = self.find('*.jpg', f'{path}')
        pix_dict = []
        for image in all_image:
            pxm = QPixmap(image)
            pix_dict.append(pxm)

        box = QGroupBox()
        box.setObjectName('main_groupbox')
        box.setStyleSheet("border:0;")

        scr = QScrollArea(self)
        pnl = QWidget(self)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        for image in list(reversed(pix_dict)):
            photo_label = QLabel()
            photo_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            photo_label.setMaximumSize(200, 120)
            photo_label.setPixmap(image.scaled(
                photo_label.width(), photo_label.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

            vbox.addWidget(photo_label)

        pnl.setLayout(vbox)
        scr.setWidget(pnl)
        scr.setWidgetResizable(True)

        group_box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        group_box_layout.addWidget(scr)
        box.setLayout(group_box_layout)
        return box


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: это минимально вопроизводимый пример чего? Как связаны этот код и текст в вопросе?

Comment: async и await пробовал?

Comment: У `Qt` есть свой `QThread`, использовать нужно его. Связанных вопросов тут по идее полно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=qthread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вам не нужны дополнительные потоки.
Все выполняется быстпро и вы можете замерить 
сколько **`мс`** выполняется метод `func_click_photo()`.

Класс `QTimer` предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры.

> void QTimer::[**singleShot**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot)(int msec, const QObject *receiver, const char *member)
>
> Эта статическая функция вызывает слот после заданного интервала времени.

---

```
QTimer.singleShot(300, self.func_updater)
```

Этот пример программы автоматически запустит слот `func_updater`
через **`300 миллисекунд`**.

---

**main.py**

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys
import time
#import threading
#from win32comext.shell import shell, shellcon

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QCamera, QCameraViewfinderSettings, \
    QCameraImageCapture, QCameraInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QCameraViewfinder
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, \
    QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QScrollArea, QPushButton, QSizePolicy


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        self.available_cameras = QCameraInfo.availableCameras()
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.viewfinder.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setObjectName('main_gridlayout')
        grid.addWidget(self.update_photo_btn(), 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.viewfinder, 1, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.showImg(), 2, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.select_camera()

    def update_photo_btn(self):
        but = QPushButton('Сделать фото и Обновить')
        but.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        but.clicked.connect(self.thread)
        return but
    
    def thread(self):
#        task_1 = threading.Thread(target=self.func_click_photo)
#        task_1.start()
#        task_1.join()
#        print(f'end task_1: {task_1}')

        self.func_click_photo()                                      # +++ <----

#        task_2 = threading.Thread(target=self.func_updater())
#        task_2.start()
#        task_2.join()
        
        QTimer.singleShot(300, self.func_updater)                    # +++ <----

    def func_click_photo(self):
        millitime = round(time.time() * 1000)
        timestamp = time.strftime(f"%d%m%Y-{millitime}")
        
#        self.capture.capture(os.path.join(f"test-{timestamp}.jpg"))
        self.capture.capture(os.path.join(
            'D:/_Qt/__Qt/Test/testtest/test/',                 # установите свой путь
            f"test-{timestamp}.jpg"
        ))

    def func_updater(self):
        grid = self.findChild(QGridLayout, 'main_gridlayout')
        box = self.findChild(QGroupBox, 'main_groupbox')

        if grid is None:
            print('Некуда вставить новый QGroupBox!')
        elif box is None:
            grid.addWidget(self.showImg(), 2, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        else:
            grid.removeWidget(box)
            box.deleteLater()
            grid.addWidget(self.showImg(), 2, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)

    def select_camera(self):
        self.camera = QCamera(self.available_cameras[0])
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)
        self.camera.setCaptureMode(QCamera.CaptureStillImage)
        self.camera.start()

        supported_formats = QCamera.supportedViewfinderResolutions(self.camera)
        height_cam = int(supported_formats[0].width())
        width_cam = int(supported_formats[0].height())

        self.setting = QCameraViewfinderSettings()
        self.setting.setResolution(height_cam, width_cam)

        self.camera.setViewfinderSettings(self.setting)
        self.capture = QCameraImageCapture(self.camera)

    def find(self, pattern, path):
        result = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for name in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                    result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
        return result

    def showImg(self):
    
#        path = shell.SHGetKnownFolderPath(shellcon.FOLDERID_Pictures)
# +++           v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v
        path = 'D:/_Qt/__Qt/Test/testtest/test'                # установите свой путь
        
        all_image = self.find('*.jpg', f'{path}')
        pix_dict = []
        for image in all_image:
            pxm = QPixmap(image)
            pix_dict.append(pxm)

        box = QGroupBox()
        box.setObjectName('main_groupbox')
        box.setStyleSheet("border: 0;")

        scr = QScrollArea(self)
        pnl = QWidget(self)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        for image in list(reversed(pix_dict)):
            photo_label = QLabel()
            photo_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            photo_label.setMaximumSize(200, 120)
            photo_label.setPixmap(image.scaled(
                photo_label.width(), photo_label.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

            vbox.addWidget(photo_label)

        pnl.setLayout(vbox)
        scr.setWidget(pnl)
        scr.setWidgetResizable(True)

        group_box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        group_box_layout.addWidget(scr)
        box.setLayout(group_box_layout)
        return box


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо, это действительно сработало, я так же думал в сторону того, чтобы в QVBoxLayout содержащий фото, в начало добавить пустой QLabel на который в момент сохранения нового изображения отрисовывать его же. Как вы считаете, это имело бы смысл? Вариант с таймером шикарный в своей простоте, но что если установленного времени будет не достаточно для какой-то не производительной машины, тогда таймер нельзя считать универсальным решением. Интересно узнать Ваше мнение. Спасибо.

Comment: @DjonyCooper по лабел, наверное можно и так, попробуйте и примите решение, которое вал больше понравится. По таймеру, проверьте на самой не производительной машине и думаю, что 300 мс вам хватит с головой. Если у вас будут проблемы - зададите новый вопрос.